# Firefox inline SVG clip-path - Works on CodePen but not on Localhost

Tags: firefox, clip-path, inline-svg

I've gotten this inline SVG clip-path to work in Chrome and Firefox on CodePen but when I try impliment it on my localhost it doesn't work in Firefox anymore. It still works fine on my localhost in Chrome so I'm sure it's got nothing to do with the url?

```css
.gem-svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.gem-wrapper {
  width: 10%;
}
.gem {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 52% 46%;
  background-color: #ff0072;
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#gem-svg-clip");
  clip-path: url("#gem-svg-clip");
}
.gem-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(149deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 51%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%), linear-gradient(30deg, #000000 0, #282828 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#gem-svg-clip");
  clip-path: url("#gem-svg-clip");
}
```

```html
<div class="gem-wrapper">
  <div class="gem">
    <span class="gem-inner">
      </span>
  </div>
</div>

<svg class="gem-svg" width="0" height="0">
  <g>
    <clipPath id="gem-svg-clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0.46 0.01, 0.50 0, 0.54 0.01, 0.97 0.24, 0.99 0.27, 1 0.31, 1 0.69, 0.99 0.73, 0.97 0.76, 0.54 0.99, 0.5 1, 0.46 0.99, 0.03 0.76, 0.01 0.73, 0 0.69, 0.0 0.31, 0.01 0.27, 0.03 0.24" />
    </clipPath>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Here's the codepen:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/IOIIOOIO/pen/LbYjQW)

Comment: Does the console have to say anything about this?

Comment: It appears blank... so I don't think so. Is there anything in particular I should be looking for? Or a console.log I can use to check or something?

Comment: Works fine for me locally, when I just copy your CSS and HTML code as shown into a new document.

Comment: ok now I'm really confused. Just to test it I quickly created an html and css page on my desktop and pasted the code in. Again, it works fine in chrome but not in firefox. Really strange. Will ask someone else to test on their PC...

Comment: Ok so I had my colleague try it on his desktop and he's having the same issue. Just to check, what you see on your side is a hexagon shape, correct?

Comment: Yes, I see the hexagon shape; looks exactly the same as in your codepen. (Firefox 49.0.2 on Win 7)

Comment: Have you tried starting your FF with all extensions disabled? (If only to _exclude_ that one of those might be to blame.)

Comment: I've solved it by explicitly pointing to my html file in the url path. Don't ask me why, but it works now.

Comment: So, for clarity to other users experiencing this issue:

In my CSS file instead of just using

 `clip-path: url("#gem-svg-clip");`

I used:

 `clip-path: url("index.html#gem-svg-clip");`

and now it works.